# lambda expression for converting double array to comma separated string

Tags: c#, string, lambda

I want to convert the double array into comma separated string. Is it doable with lambda expression:

```
double [] test = new double [] {1 ,2, 3} ;
```

for example, I want to convert above array in comma separated string using lambda expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this .Net version 4+

```
var result = String.Join(",", test);
```

read more about [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx).

It's not lambda expression, but I think that this is what you were looking for. Lamda expression are just delegates, so you don't need lambda here :)

[Lambda Expression c#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx)

EDIT:

for version .Net < 4.0 `String.Join` accepts only `string[]` (thanks @SonerGönül) and you need to use this:

```
var result = String.Join(",", test.Select(x=>x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

which will convert `double [] test` to string array. [Example](http://ideone.com/6CMOAS)

Answer (score 1):

If you need the doubles to be formatted in a special way you could do it like this:

```
var result = String.Join(",", test.Select(d => d.ToString("000000")));
```